# Как в Active Directory выдать права только на выбрасывание пользователя из системы?

Tags: windows, active-directory

У нас есть несколько серверов в Active Directory, на которых регулярно зависают пользовательские сеансы. Есть специальный человек, которому звонят и он эти сеансы должен удалять. Можно ли так разрулить пользовательскими правами, чтобы данный человек имел административное право только на удаление сессий и никаких административных прав по другим вопросам? И, собственно, как?

Comment: Может лучше узнать почему зависают сеансы? Ну или если очень лениво - то написать скрипт, который будет эти сеансы грохать?

Comment: Если лень разбираться с причиной зависания, то можно создать триггер, вызывающий завершение определенной сессии. А потом организовать пользователю возможность вызова триггера.

Comment: И как пользователь может вызвать триггер, если у него висит сеанс и он, например, видит в загрузке чёрный экран без ничего?

Comment: Я понял из вопроса, что  речь шла об операторе сервера (специальном человеке). В случае, когда речь идет пользователе, который не может подключится к сеансу, - видимо, нужно использовать триггер, срабатывающий на подключение к серверу. А далее уже нужно анализировать кто подключается, было ли это переподключение или этой новый сеанс. Проще, наверное разобраться в причинах зависания.

Comment: Поверьте, ели бы это было _проще_ — вопрос бы звучал совершенно иначе. По факту право удалять сессии подключенных пользователей это эксклюзивное право администратора домена (и выше). Давать такие права рядовому администратору…